# How to open a file on BOX cloud in webview?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, box-api

I am trying to open a file present on my box cloud in `UIWebView`. For this purpose, I tried to load the webView with `[[boxItem.rawResponseJSON objectForKey:@"shared_link"] objectForKey:@"download_url"]` as well as `[[boxItem.rawResponseJSON objectForKey:@"shared_link"] objectForKey:@"url"]`. With this or any other approach it is sending me the authentication challenge and not allowing me to show the file in webView.

I did some analysis on web, isn't there any way to show box file in `UIWebView`, other than downloading the file in local cache and showing from there?

Comment: What are the security settings for your shared link? is that publicly open shared linK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches for presenting a Box file in UIWebView:
1) Use Box View API for presenting the API.
2) Use Box Content API and download a file in Bundle/Document's(local) and the present it in UIWebView.

Here is a tut for using BoxView: http://developers.box.com/viewing-your-first-document/

Login to developer.Box.com first and then u can have access to the link.